# Need Possible IF Statement Excel Formula

Tags: excel, formula

[Require assistance with excel formula to subtract numbers from cells F2 & I2 if no data is in cell K2. If data is in cell K2,then I need formula to subtract F1 & K2 only.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c0NC.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Well, based on what you asked and what I understand, then the following may help:
[image]

If you are going to drag this down then you may need to control which cells move.

Edit, just spotted you said subtract so:

```
=IF(K2="",F2-I2,F1-K2)
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: @emald you can use the check or tick box to accept the answer as well. Cheers anyway, glad it helped.